# Proper Call of runParser Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, compilation

I have written a set of parsing functions, but don't know how to call them properly.

Here is how I am trying to invoke the `parser` function.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    tempDatabase <- readFile "films.txt"
    let i = lines tempDatabase
    let database = runParser parser () database
    putStrLn "Enter your name: "
    username <- getLine
    userInterface database username
    appendFile "films.txt" (show database)
    putStrLn "Your changes to the database have been successfully saved."
```

I get the following type error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘String -> Either ParseError Film’
                   with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: SourceName
      Actual type: String -> Either ParseError Film

Couldn't match expected type ‘[Film]’
            with actual type ‘String -> Either ParseError Film’
Probable cause: ‘database’ is applied to too few arguments
```

For more context, these are all the functions for the parser (which are working correctly).

```
str :: Parser String
str = many1 (noneOf ",")

int :: Parser Int
int = read <$> many1 digit

tup :: Parser UserRatings
tup = do user <- str
         _ <- oneOf ","
         rating <- int
         return (user, rating)

parser :: Parser Film
parser = do title <- str
            _ <- oneOf ","
            director <- str
            _ <- oneOf ","
            year <- int
            _ <- oneOf ","
            ratings <- sepBy tup (oneOf ",")
            eof
            return (title, director, year, ratings)
```

and this is the `userInterface`

```
userInterface :: [Film] -> String -> IO()
userInterface filmList user = do
                              putStrLn "\n............................\n"
                              putStrLn "Welcome to the Film web Database     "
                              putStrLn "............................"
                              putStrLn "1. - Add a new film to the database\n"
                              putStrLn "2. - Print all films in the database\n"
                              putStrLn "3. - Print all films that a particular user is a fan of\n"
                              putStrLn "4. - Print all fans of the film of your choice\n"
                              putStrLn "5. - Print all films that were released during a particular period\n"
                              putStrLn "6. - Be a fan of the film of your choice!\n"
                              putStrLn "7. - Print the average number of fans for the films starring a particular actor\n"
                              putStrLn "8. - Print the names of actors who have co-starred in at least one film\n"
                              putStrLn "0. - Quit and update database\n"
                              putStrLn "****************************************************************************\n"
                              putStr "Enter a number to perform an action or 0 to exit and save the database: "
                              userChoice <-getLine
                              case userChoice of
                                  "1" -> do
                                         putStrLn $ displayAllFilmsString filmList
                                         userInterface filmList user
```

Comment: You did look at `runParser`'s documentation, right? It expects a `SourceName`, which can be empty. By the way, since you use `()` as state, you can use `parse` instead. Also, you don't want to define `database` in terms of `database` but `tempDatabase`. And depending on whether you actually parse all contents, you'll end up with your old problem from Monday(?).

Comment: okay so how can i write it? do you have any clue?

Comment: no i changed most of the code man at this point the only thing i want to do is to compile it and be able to just make some calls from some functional code ive written. This is btw a project of 400+ lines so please can you help me do that? it's been a week that i'm working on it can you send me the exact call?

Comment: Well, here's a clue: what's strange about the following line? `let database = runParser parser () database`

Comment: i only have database as a variable i use and there are 2 functions which take at least 1 variable each

Comment: Final hint (I'm going off for today): `let ********database******** = runParser parser () ********database********`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105847/discussion-between-max-and-zeta).

Comment: @Zeta Please help me runParser's documentation is very confusing. and i'm kind of thinking that database should be first.` let database *** ` because it has not in scope errors

Comment: The thing that the other commenter was trying to point out is that `database = runParser parser () database` is self-referential in a way that doesn't make any sense - the result of the parse is apparently the input to the parser as well. This is completely seperate from the fact that you haven't applied `runParser` to enough arguments - as the error tells you. You probably want `database = runParser parser () "" tempDatabase`

Comment: @user2407038 what arguments should i pass on this line afterwards instead of just database?
`userInterface database username`

i get an error `Couldn't match expected type ‘[Film]’
                with actual type ‘Either ParseError Film’`